# What is a 'type assertion' between the function name and parameters, on calling a function?

Tags: typescript, assertion

In this [Typescript React starter guide](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-React-Starter#creating-a-store) it gives:

```
import { createStore } from 'redux';

interface StoreState {
    languageName: string;
    enthusiasmLevel: number;
}

function enthusiasm(state: StoreState, action: EnthusiasmAction): StoreState {
    // returns a StoreState
}
const store = createStore<StoreState>(enthusiasm, {
     enthusiasmLevel: 1,
     languageName: 'TypeScript',   
});
```

What is this  assertion doing there?

I couldn't find where this syntax is defined, and can't "deduce" what it means.

Comment: Have a look at [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html)

Comment: Thanks - I'd pay that as an answer: sometimes simple is correct and good :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This isn't a type assertion, it is a type argument, which is used for generic types.

## Type Assertions

Firstly, here's a type assertion...

```
const x = <HTMLAnchorElement>document.getElementById('myLink');
```

The type assertion appears before the expression and says "actually this is an anchor, not just a general element".

## Generics

Now let's look at generics...

This function takes a string and returns it.

```
function example(input: string): string {
    return input;
}
```

Now we can add another function that takes a number and returns it, but actually our function doesn't care about the type of the parameter, or the return type - as long as they are the same...

So instead of repeating the function for each type, we can say, "the type will be `T`, where `T` will be defined later on".

```
function example<T>(input: T): T {
    return input;
}
```

## Explicit Type Argument

When you use something generic (it can be a class, or a function, or a method), you can supply the type argument explicitly, like this:

```
function example<T>(input: T): T {
    return input;
}

const str = example<string>('str');

const num = example<number>(3);
```

They look a bit like type assertions, but they appear in a different location.

## Implicit Type Argument

In many cases, you don't need to explicitly pass the type argument, as the compiler can work it out for you.

```
function example<T>(input: T): T {
    return input;
}

const str = example('str');

const num = example(3);
```