# Typescript generics syntax: what does <Type> achieve?

Tags: typescript, generics

Reading the typescript handbook on generics: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html

I got confused on the syntax for below example:

```
function loggingIdentity<Type>(arg: Type[]): Type[] {
  console.log(arg.length);
  return arg;
}
```

I understand that:

1. `arg: Type[]` specifies the input argument.
2. `Type[]` that comes before `{ ... }` specifies the return type

However,

3. What is the purpose of `<Type>` in `loggingIdentity<Type>`?

What does it achieve?

Comment: That's described in the article you linked, see "Hello World of Generics". Can you elaborate what you didn't understand about that section?

Comment: Maybe this link might help you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47284987/what-is-a-type-assertion-between-the-function-name-and-parameters-on-calling

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the use of angular brackets like methodname<string>() in typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52531416/what-is-the-use-of-angular-brackets-like-methodnamestring-in-typescript)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `<Type>` part is what makes it a generic: it defines a variable of sorts (which you can name anything you want, though `T` or `Type` are common). This is the placeholder for any type.

So you can call `loggingIdentity(arg)` where `arg` is of type `number` or `string` or any complex type you want. The declaration with `<Type>` is what allows it; and the usage of `Type` in the argument and the return type is your declaration that the method will return the same type of value as was passed in.